# webdriver page_source not getting the same html code as when I view the page source manualy

Tags: python, selenium

So exactly as the title says. When the webdriver opens a chrome window to browse the website i view the page source and everything's good. Then I use the page_source attribute of the webdriver object but it returns a string that is different. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
chrome.get('the link represents a chess match played in real time on lichess.org')
with open("page_content.txt",'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(chrome.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

My purpose is to train a neural network to play chess by analyzing the moves of two human players.
I know I could do it easier (using a database), but I want to get familiar with selenium.

Comment: It would help if you included the link you're trying to scrape information from instead of a description, as well as what it is you need to scrape. As it is your problem cannot be reproduced. See [the asking guide on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i just made a video so you can that the page_content from selenium is different from google chrome view source. https://youtu.be/a6iLB358Qxs